# Two UserControls, one binds, one doesn't

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have two very simple UserControls in a simple WinRT demo project. No Viewmodel--mostly just colored boxes for layout exploration. The first UserControl I created works fine. The second, very similar one, won't bind to any properties--it shows up as blank.

The first UserControl looks like this:

```
    <UserControl
    x:Class="Demo.SmallStartTile"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Demo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="SmallStartTileUC"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


    <Grid x:Name="SmallTileGrid"
        Margin="0,0,8,8"
        Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=SmallStartTileUC}"
        >

        <Rectangle
            Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=SmallStartTileUC}"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            />

        <TextBlock x:Name="SmallTileTitle" 
            Text="{Binding TileText, ElementName=SmallStartTileUC}" 
            Style="{StaticResource SmallTileHeader}"/>

        <Path x:Name="IconPath" 
            Style="{StaticResource SmallTileIcon}" 
            Data="{Binding TileIconPathData, ElementName=SmallStartTileUC}" />

    </Grid>




    </UserControl>

namespace Demo
{
    public sealed partial class SmallStartTile : UserControl
    {
    public static DependencyProperty TileTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TileText", typeof(string), typeof(SmallStartTile), new PropertyMetadata("tile content"));

    public string TileText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TileTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TileTextProperty, value); }
    }


    public static DependencyProperty TileIconPathDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TileIconPathData", typeof(string), typeof(SmallStartTile), new PropertyMetadata("F0"));

    public string TileIconPathData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TileIconPathDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TileIconPathDataProperty, value); }
    }



    public SmallStartTile()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

And the second one, which I made just like the first one by clicking Add New Item and picking UserControl in Blend:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Demo.SmallMediaTile"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Demo"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="SmallMediaTileUC"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid 
    Margin="0,0,8,8"
    Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=SmallMediaTileUC}"
    >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle 
        Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=SmallMediaTileUC}"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        />

    <Viewbox 
        Margin="30" 
        Child="{Binding Content, ElementName=SmallMediaTileUC}">
    </Viewbox>

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Text="{Binding SourceText, ElementName=SmallMediaTileUC}" 
        Style="{StaticResource SmallMusicTileHeader}"/>

</Grid>

</UserControl>


namespace Demo
{
    public sealed partial class SmallMediaTile : UserControl
    {

    public static DependencyProperty SourceTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SourceText", typeof(string), typeof(SmallMediaTile), new PropertyMetadata("source"));

    public string SourceText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SourceTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceTextProperty, value); }
    }



    public SmallMediaTile()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

I use the UserControl in the main Page like this:

```
                            <local:SmallMediaTile x:Name="Source1Tile"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                            SourceText="Radio"
                            Background="Blue"
                            BorderBrush="Red">
                            <local:SmallMediaTile.Content>
                            <Canvas x:Name="radio_icon" Height="68" Width="34">
                                <Path Data="F1M299.6182,396.2988C299.6182,389.7208,297.0722,383.5548,292.4572,378.8398L288.6162,382.6758C292.2022,386.3718,294.1842,391.1778,294.1842,396.2988C294.1842,401.4238,292.2022,406.2368,288.6162,409.9328L292.4572,413.7738C297.0722,409.0538,299.6182,402.8808,299.6182,396.2988" Fill="White" Height="34.934" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="16.501" Width="11.002"/>
                                <Path Data="F1M311.1738,396.2988C311.1738,386.6278,307.4348,377.5528,300.6788,370.6208L296.8258,374.4618C302.5658,380.3698,305.7398,388.0798,305.7398,396.2988C305.7398,404.5218,302.5658,412.2298,296.8258,418.1428L300.6788,421.9898C307.4348,415.0498,311.1738,405.9718,311.1738,396.2988" Fill="White" Height="51.369" Canvas.Left="8.21" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="8.282" Width="14.348"/>
                                <Path Data="F1M322.7578,396.2988C322.7578,383.5298,317.8508,371.5348,308.9638,362.3388L305.1168,366.1748C312.9758,374.3538,317.3338,384.9778,317.3338,396.2988C317.3338,407.6208,312.9758,418.2488,305.1168,426.4268L308.9638,430.2748C317.8508,421.0698,322.7578,409.0798,322.7578,396.2988" Fill="White" Height="67.936" Canvas.Left="16.501" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="17.641"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            </local:SmallMediaTile.Content>
                        </local:SmallMediaTile>
```

The first one picks up all the properties and displays like I expect, but the second one only picks up the Viewbox content. I've looked through SO and been googling but can't figure out what the problem is. Sorry if this is longwinded.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious but could you check for binding errors in your debug output window in Visual Studio?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? I can see the control crashing for me when I try to bind the Child of the Viewbox to a non-existent Content property of the UserControl, but if I remove that - it seems to work fine.

Comment: I think my teammate figured out the answer. The problem is the Viewbox. Setting the Viewbox content in the page XAML overwrites the UserControl's content. So the real question is: how do I insert Canvas content into a UserControl? I would close this question and ask that one.

Comment: Edited the question to show the UserControl in the main Page, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: The answer to the other one would be - it depends. It depends on how you want to approach this. You can use a templated ContentControl instead of the UserControl and modify its template to add the TextBlock etc. You can also keep using a UserControl and add some other dependency property that will be bound to your Viewbox's content (`Child`).

Comment: Thanks @Filip. I can also add dependency properties that I could use to fill in fields in a templated ContentControl, right?

Comment: Sure, but in a ContentControl you get a Content property that a ContentPresenter in its template can bind to and you can still put some other controls around that. It seems like setting Content property on a UserControl will replace its logical children.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I found an article that explained what I was trying to do would replace the UserControl's content. What I was trying to do essentially set the Content twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, the problem is the UserControl's content can only be set once. When I bind the Viewbox Content to the UserControl content, the existing XAML is replaced. So, a blank box but for what I'm passing in. I guess to do what I had hoped, I'd need to make a custom control. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your root `Grid` is set as the `Content` of the `UserControl` while the `Viewbox` you have is trying to bind its `Child` property to the `Content` of the `UserControl` that is its ascendant. That is not allowed since the root `Grid` is already a parent of the `UserControl` and XAML controls can only exist in one place in the UI.